# Cannot Run Macro, May be Disabled

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a code that shows all comments when a worksheet is activated.  Then 5 seconds later all the commends are hidden.  I am receiving an error at the 5 second mark where it says "Cannot run the macro (filepath). The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

I've gone to the trust center and checked the box in the macro page and enabled all macros. I've added the filepathe on the shared drive to my trusted locations. I've tried copying the file to my docs and running it locally.  No luck.

What gives?

```
Dim TimeToRun

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator

    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CloseComments"

End Sub

Sub CloseComments()
    Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
End Sub
```

**Error Message Screenshot**
[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Comment: "Sub CloseComments" appears to be on a WorkSheet code page.  Move it to a standard Module.  i.e. VBA IDE   Insert Menu->Module

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your `Sub CloseComments` to a standard module instead of the sheet module and it should work.